# How to detect if device is headed towards a specific point direction

Tags: iphone, coordinates, detect, angle

I have my current location from CLLocation,

and I have another location-  also an CLLocation.

I would like to detect when my device is heading towards that other location.

(I can calculate the distance in meters between this points- but can't workout

the calculation of an accurate angle to compare with the device current heading)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using CLLocation's built-in `course` property?

Comment: How can I define the point to wich I want to find the course?

Answer (score 0):

**To Be deleted**

One approach could be to continuously calculate the distance between current location and target location. if the distance decreases, your device is moving towards the the target.

---

In a real world szenario (car in city, car in mountainous country e.g. Switzerland) this  doesn't work. You would need some array of way-points (e.g. intersections) that lead towards the target and continuosly look for the closest waypoint.

Comment: The device is not moving-
I have 2 locations- the devices location and the other one-
I need to know when the device is heading (not moving towards- just heading) towards that point.

Comment: Aha. Language issue, I guess. In this context my answer makes zero sense. I'll mark it as wiki and delete, once you had a chance to read this.

Comment: Thanks,
Is this "azimuth" that I am looking for?